# MODX Revo: в чанке получить значение из заданной таблицы

Tags: modx, доступ

Модекс только начал осваивать, вопрос из раздела 2х2=4
Как получить строку value ("с 00:00 до 00:00") из таблицы `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` выбрав по параметрам
tmplvarid = 18 AND contentid = 447
Пишу так, и это не работает:

```
<li class="p_time">Время работы: <span class="purpule">
[[!pdoResources?class=`modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`
&select=`value`
&where=`tmplvarid = '18' AND contentid = '447'`]]
</span></li>
```

[image: Таблица modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[pdoResources?
    &class  = `modTemplateVarResource`
    &select = `value`
    &sortby = `id` 
    &where  = `tmplvarid = '18' AND contentid = '447'`
    &tpl    = `@INLINE [[+value]]`
]]
```

Если только начинаете изучать modx, рекомендую вам сразу обратить внимание на шаблонизатор Fenom. Ускорите работу сайта в разы

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. Только я так и не понял, почему данные пришли из таблицы modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues?
Где это указано? Или это связано с modTemplateVarResource?
Где еще разные связи можно посмотретть?

Comment: @Старший Доктор  В modx взаимодействие с таблицами осуществляется через модели. В данном случае класс модели называется modTemplateVarResource. Все соответствия базовых таблиц вы можете посмотреть здесь: https://webstool.ru/modx-sootvetstvie-nazvaniya-klassov-s-nazvaniyami-tablicz-v-mysql.html